# Accesing a int value from a method into another method?

Tags: java, int

I have a method, which generates a random number, heres the code for it:

```
    public int generateNumber(){
    int randomnum = generator.nextInt(5);
    System.out.println(randomnum);
    return randomnum;
}
```

Now, I want to acces the randomnum int value, into another method, in the same class file, in an if-statement. Like this:

```
public DrawPanel(){  
    timer.schedule(new LeTimer(), 0, 1*1000);

    if(randomnum == 3){
         System.out.println("3 has been counted.");
    }
}
```

How would I do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

declare the int in class scope then all methods can access it

```
class
{
    <class scope variables>

    method1() { }
    method2() { }
}
```

or simply call the method directly inside the other method

```
if(generateNumber() == 3){
     System.out.println("3 has been counted.");
}
```

Comment: Oh, I got it already, I accidently put the if-statement after the return randomnum, so it was unreachable code, I got it now, thanks.